# SpiderMonkey 38 compilation error

Tags: c++

I was using Spidermonkey 24 earlier but then moved to version 38 yesterday. But the problem is I'm unable to compile any program using this version. I tried compiling the sample code that came within but it gives the following error:

```
sudo g++ -I /home/pi/mozjs-38.0.0/js/src/build_OPT.OBJ/dist/include/ -L     /home/pi/mozjs-38.0.0/js/src/build_OPT.OBJ/dist/lib/ sample.cpp -o sample -lmozjs-38 -lz -lpthread -ldl

In file included from sample.cpp:1:0:
sample.h:6:21: fatal error: jscntxt.h: No such file or directory
 #include "jscntxt.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

Note: The path to that header is already specified in the command.
I was successfully compiling the program using the same command with spidermonkey24.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you compile with `sudo`?!?!?

Comment: I always have a habit of using sudo. i know its sometimes wrong. I do understand the consequence of using sudo while mkdir, etc but while compiling its fine I guess. It doesn't make any countable difference.

Comment: instead of `sudo` insert into cmd line `strace` and post log of strace somewhere, this help understand where really gcc search header file

Comment: It does not make sense to use `sudo` all the time. You could just log in as root, the result would be same, and you'd save some keystrokes.

Comment: BTW. I believe you should not put spaces between `-I`, `-L` and their arguments.

Comment: BTW. Did you actually install SpiderMonkey (`make install` or equivalent)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :-) i always love those.

Comment: yes I installed. Downloaded the source and compiled it as per the official steps. Ver 24 is working fine. version 38 is the problem. i just need to figure out the compile command for v38 programs.

Comment: and the spaces doesn't affect -I , -L